# Identifying toilet connector size

Tags: toilet

I need to replace the toilet connector line in my bathroom (the old one failed catastrophically and flooded everything).

I'm stuck because I can't figure out what size is correct. The pipes are quite old and it appears that the old line used a no-longer-standard size nut to connect to the valve coming out of the wall.

1/2 FIPs is too large, 1/2 COMP is too small. The hardware store near me has a plumbing-specific thread checker board, but the nut on the end of the old supply line doesn't fit onto any of the threads.

I'm adding a photo of the old supply line and the valve -- ignore my temporary Rube Goldberg solution to the problem.

Does anyone have advice on how I can figure out what size I need and where I could buy the correct supply line and/or an adapter?

[image: unknown size nut]
[image: valve]

Comment: Rube would have been proud of that ;)

Comment: that is just asking for a flooded home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the valve outlet is an odd size, replace it with a standard one.

It looks like you have a 1/2" threaded connection coming out of the wall. If you can shut off the water to your place (and confirm it's off before proceeding), remove the valve and replace it with a 1/2" FIP x 3/8 compression stop valve. You can then use a standard toilet supply line.

When removing and installing the new valve, be sure to back-wrench the nipple coming out of the wall.

Comment: Ok, I was starting to think this might be the answer. Thank you!